# Does plain object in JavaScript V8 has hidden class?

Tags: javascript, v8

I've read hidden class at [V8 Design Elements:Fast Property Access](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access).

Objects in the example is created by a constructor

```
var p1 = new Point(1,2)
```

p1 has a hidden class for fast access it's property 'x', 'y'.

```
var p2 = {x:1,y:2}
```

so, my question#1 is: does p2 share a hidden class with p1?

and, if p2 do has a hidden class, will following code change the hidden class?(question#2)

```
delete p2.x
```

Here is the article make me ask this question:

[Writing Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/)

Just read **DE-REFERENCING MISCONCEPTIONS** part.

Is this article right about deleting property?(question#3)

Comment: If I understand correctly: yes, no. If you delete from an object, it no longer has a class.

Comment: I'd say yes, yes, yes. @Jan: It still had the class with y properties, no?

Comment: @Bergi that's what I would think, but unless changed in V8, that's not what V8 does. See that article.

Comment: Oh, we've been wrong on question #1. While the linked articles don't state it, the prototype of the object would affect the hidden class it is starting off with.

Answer (score 0):

so, my question#1 is: does p2 share a hidden class with p1? 
Answer: No, Only objects created using same constructor will share hidden classes.

Answer to #2 question: Deleting a property on p2 will change the hidden class of p2.

I have verified this by using Heap memory snapshot option available on chrome dev tools.

Thanks,